# Get store config based on pattern

Tags: configuration

If i have the following store config paths:

```
catalog/my_custom_section/value_1
catalog/my_custom_section/value_2
catalog/my_custom_section/value_3
catalog/my_custom_section/value_4
catalog/my_custom_section/value_5
```

Is there a way to grab all of these at once in an array using `getStoreConfig()` instead of having to do the following:

```
$values = array();
$values[] = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/my_custom_section/value_1');
$values[] = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/my_custom_section/value_2');
etc..
```

Obviously i can improve that with a loop but im asking if there is a way in magento to do something like: `Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/my_custom_section/value_%');` and get an array back.

Comment: Any reason for down-voting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/my_custom_section')`.
You should get an array with all the values under the node `catalog/my_custom_section`.
The problem is that if you have other fields except `value_{$i}` you will get those fields also.